# Rails, Appcelerator, and JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, appcelerator

I'm trying to get my appcelerator mobile app to pull in JSON from my rails app.

Here is how I'm pulling in the JSON in appcelerator:

loader.open("GET","http://xxx/mobile_api");

This works for the following URLs:
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mobtuts
http://www.coovents.com/tit_json_local.php

In my rails app, I generate the JSON like this:
@locations_json = @locations.to_json
render :text => @locations_json

I actually copied the text output from my rails app and created a php text file (Coovents) and that works.

The JSON generated by my app isn't working with appeclerator, but the JSON generated by Twitter works fine.  When I copy the JSON generated by my app and paste it in a separate file, that works too.

Comment: can you post the JSON that your app is generating?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your PHP is serving it with "text/html"?

Try serving with "application/javascript" or "application/json"?